# Re-map a number from one range to another

Tags: go, arduino

Is there any equivalent in go for the Arduino [map](http://arduino.cc/en/reference/map) function?

> map(value, fromLow, fromHigh, toLow, toHigh)
>
> Description
>
> Re-maps a number from one range to another. That is, a value of
>   fromLow would get mapped to toLow, a value of fromHigh to toHigh,
>   values in-between to values in-between, etc

If not, how would I implement this in go?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there any equivalent in go for the Arduino `map` function?

The standard library, or more specifically the [`math` package](http://golang.org/pkg/math/), does not offer such a function, no.

> If not, how would I implement this in go?

By taking the original code and translating it to Go. C and Go are very related syntactically and therefore this task is very, very easy. The manual page for `map` that you linked gives you the code. A translation to go is, as already mentioned, trivial.

Original from the [page you linked](http://arduino.cc/en/reference/map):

> For the mathematically inclined, here's the whole function
>
> ```
> long map(long x, long in_min, long in_max, long out_min, long out_max)
> {
>   return (x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min;
> }
> ```

You would translate that to something like

```
func Map(x, in_min, in_max, out_min, out_max int64) int64 {
    return (x - in_min) * (out_max - out_min) / (in_max - in_min) + out_min
}
```

[Here](http://play.golang.org/p/b9oHKhv_ed) is an example on the go playground.

Note that `map` is not a valid function name in Go since there is already the `map` <del>built-in type which makes `map` a reserved keyword.</del> keyword for defining map types, similar to the `[]T` syntax.